# How to import module with MPI capabilities and use it in my module?

Tags: python-3.x, mpi4py

I am making a module that depends on another module with MPI capabilities. When using the MPI module as the developer states I should...

```
# script_one.py
from mpi_module import *
some_mpi_module_function()
```

... and execute with `mpirun -n 4 script_one.py` everything works as intended with complicated tasks split among processors within `some_mpi_module_function()`.

In my module, I am going against the developer's advice of importing without namspaces:

```
# my_module
import mpi_module
def my_module_function():
    some_task()
    mpi_module.some_mpi_module_function()
```

But, when I import my module from a script...

```
# script_two.py
import my_module
my_module.my_module_function()
```

... and I run `mpirun -n 4 script_two.py`, four instances of my script are run and `mpi_module.some_mpi_module_function()` is run sequentially of each processor.

How can I get my module to use the other module's MPI capabilities?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example of "script" and "your module"? Just something with the right imports and a print statement maybe?

Comment: I guess you already have "your module", but I'm not sure I understand what the problem in "script" is.

Comment: I've clarified my question a bit with some pseudocode.

Comment: Please present a full [mcve] of all involved scripts and an exact observed vs expected behavior. Where does the developer advise to import without namespaces?